# group does not show zero count request by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im stuck at getting the following to show count group by month even if its zero count for that month.

From rails console if I use:

```
StorageRequest.select("MONTH(created_at) as month, COUNT(id) as total").where(:created_at => 3.months.ago.to_date..Date.today).group("month")
```

Im getting:

| month | total |

| 9     | 4     |

Where I'm expecting to get:

| month | total |

| 8 | 0 |

| 9 | 4 |

| 10 | 0 |

How should I go about this.

Thank you.

Comment: Since (from the looks of things) there aren't any entries for August or October in the storage_request (again, I assume) table in the database, that `where` clause isn't finding *anything* for those months.  I think that, if you really want to this kind of prettyprinting, you're going to have to write some kind of wrapper to iterate over the results of that query and print out the month, with a total of zero, for any "missing" months.

Comment: Correct there are aren't any entries for this months. Any idea on how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your database, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Seconding what @PinnyM said: it looks like ActiveRecord is giving you an inner join (the default) when you need an outer join.

Comment: Im using MySQL database

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky, but something like this should work:

```
results = {}
StorageRequest.select("MONTH(created_at) as month, COUNT(id) as total").where(:created_at => 3.months.ago.to_date..Date.today).group("month").each { |m| results[m.month] = m.total }
(1..12).map { |m| [m, results[m] || 0] }
```

Basically load the results from the database, then build a custom data structure by iterating over the months.  For the custom structure, set the count to the value from the database if available, 0 otherwise.